# python create directory structure based on the date

Tags: python, python-2.7

I used the following function to created dirctory based on today date ,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time, datetime, os

today = datetime.date.today()  

todaystr = today.isoformat()   

os.mkdir(todaystr)
```

so the out  put will be

```
/2015-12-22/
```

what i'm looking to is adjust the structure which is create dirctories structure based on day date as following

```
/2015/12/22
/2015/12/23
etc
```

when ever i run the function it will  check the date and make sure the folder is exist other wise will create it ..
any tips to follow here ?

Answer (score 12):

Consider using [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) instead. Which you can use to defined a format to your liking. You will also need to use `os.makedirs` as described by @Valijon below.

```
os.makedirs(time.strftime("/%Y/%m/%d"), exist_ok=True)
```

You can also append a given time to create a time-stamp in the past or in the future.

```
time.strftime("/%Y/%m/%d", time.gmtime(time.time()-3600)) # -1 hour
```

Also note that your path is a bit dangerous, unless you want to create folders directly under the root partition.

Note that `makedirs` will raise an exception by default if the directory already exists, you can specify `exist_ok=True` to avoid this, read more about it in the docs for [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs).

---

Since Python 3.4, the module [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) was Introduced which offers some directory and file creation features.

```py
import time
import pathlib
pathlib.Path(time.strftime("/%Y/%m/%d")).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Should you not first check if the directory exists? `mkdir` doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: @pushkin correct, a bit tired so missed the fact that he used mkdir instead of makedirs. Corrected my code.

Comment: Since python 3.2 Use `exist_okay` parameter in `os.makedirs` parameter to not throw an exception if the directory already exists

Comment: @schuess Thanks for pointing it out :) I guess we who answer (or answered) a lot of questions should go back every now and then and re-visit the relevance of our questions on a routine basis. So thanks for poking me to fix this answer!

Answer (score 2):

Just change `os.mkdir` to `os.makedirs`

```
os.makedirs(today.strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
```

Comment: Is `mkdirs` supposed to be `makedirs`? If so, `makedirs` raises an exception if the directory already exists, so I think you should first check.

Comment: Since 3.2: use `exist_ok` to prevent `os.makedirs` from throwing an exception if dir already exists